# Help me find my friend Bill

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

My friend Bill can get a bit "eccentric" if he doesn't take his medication, and I'm afraid he's off them again.

He hadn't been answering his phone for the last week or two, so I went over to his apartment today to check on him. There was nobody there, but I found this note he had left for me:

> JOTA,
>
> HAD TO FLEE MEN WITH BIG AXE.
>
> Q: WHO?
>
> A: KGB AGENT AND NAZI!
>
> GONE TO LIVE IN NEW LAND.
>
> HINT NOT IN NOTE!!!
>
> BILL

It looks like he's having another episode, and I think he's actually left the country this time. I have to find him for his own safety, but he said there wasn't any hint to his destination in the note. I can't find any other clues in his apartment. I don't even know where to start looking for him.

Can anybody here help me figure out where in the world Bill is hiding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The letters not in the note are C, P, R, S, U, and Y

meaning he’s hiding in

> Cyprus

Comment: Correct, and well done.